# Do all pages must use react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, next.js

I am making my first website (to test myself) using react and node.js with next.js. Is it possible to not to use react for example on the registration page? I guess it would be easier wthout it to handle new users data to DB?

Comment: You can use React or any JavaScript on any page or chose not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, you can use React on as many or few pages as you want.

You also don't have to build the entire page with React. React can be mounted into any DOM element on the page.

But also no, it won't necessarily be easier to do the registration page without React. If you want to use React, you should get comfortable with passing data to and from the server with AJAX.